# What does the code of the designated initializer look like?

Tags: objective-c

I've looked into books and multiple forum posts in regards to the init and initializer concepts, but I still can't get my head around the designated initializer.

What does the code for it look like?

In this code below, which code line is the designated initializer?

```
-( Fraction *) initWith (int) n over: (int) d
{
    self  = [ super init];
    if (self) 
        [self setTo: n over: d ];
    return self; 
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're a little confused about what the phrase "designated initializer" means. A class might have several initalizers. Let's take a fictional Cat class. It might have the following initializers:

```
- init
- initWithName:
- initWithName:breed:
- initWithName:breed:age:
```

The designated initializer is the one that actually performs that class's initialization and calls through to `super`. The last one there, `initWithName:breed:age` would probably be the designated initializer, because it gets the most data. It might be implemented like this:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name breed:(CatBreed)breed age:(NSUInteger)age {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _name = [name copy];
        _breed = breed;
        _age = age;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This does all the work of setting up the instance. The other initializers would be implemented in terms of this one. For example, another one might be implemented like this:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    return [self initWithName:name breed:CatBreedTabby age:0];
}
```

So to change the class's initialization behavior in a subclass, you only need to change the designated initializer and you get the others for free.

Comment: Thanks Chuck for a great response. I have one more question. When super is initialized, does that create an object of that superclass, which is then stored in self?

Comment: @DanielLee: No. `super` is a keyword that is equivalent to `self`, but runs the superclass's version of the method instead of the current class's. So it just runs the superclass initializer on `self` to set up any instance variables etc. inherited from the superclass.

Comment: Thank you Chuck. I know I've already said this is my last question, but I think I need clarification on one more thing before I could fully understand init. What does it really mean to initialize a method? Does that mean after a class memory is allocated, the class object is given "initial" (as in initialized) values which are zero? And, what is self? is self the object? The instance variables you are referring to, are they the instance variable like *myFraction that holds the reference to data or like numerator thats stored in the object? Sorry for a load of questions.

Comment: I've been trying to find clarifications on these through the web without asking basic questions for a couple of hours now. But, unfortunately, I had to because I haven't made any breakthrough on my own.

Comment: @DanielLee: Yes, an initializer is a method that sets up the object to some initial state. This is not necessarily "everything is zero" — for example, the `initWithName:breed:age:` method shown above will initialize the instance variables to whatever values to pass in. As for the rest of your questions, it sounds like you could use a good introduction to Objective-C in general. Apple has one at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html — that will give you a good foundation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Every initializer must call a designated initializer in its implementation.

In this case the `[super init]` call is the call to the superclass initializer of the class, so this is likely to be the designed initializer itself.

Designated initializers can be more than one, depending on the specific class. In order to find which are those, you need to check the documentation.

For instance `UIView` has two designated initializers

- `-initWithFrame:`
- `-initWithCoder:`

and you must call one of the two in any other initializer you may have in your custom `UIView` subclass.

For more details, see [Multiple Initializers and the Designated Initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) (thanks Seamus)

Comment: For more details, see "Multiple Initializers and the Designated Initializer" in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Comment: Small clarification: `[super init]` is a call to the *superclass's* initializer — it isn't the designated initializer of the class in question.